# how to change useState's state without render in functional component

Tags: react-native

how to change useState's state without render in functional component

```js
    const [imageId, setimageId] = useState(0);
    const Slide = () => {
            return (
                slides.map((item, index) => (
                    <View style={styles.slide}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setimageId(index)} >
                            <Image source={item.image}} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                ))
            )
        }
```

when I change state in onPress slide component re-renders and images load again

so how can I change the state without rendering the slide component

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042424/react-native-how-to-stop-child-component-rerendering-on-state-change

Comment: Nooruddin-lakhani thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create a component that will be inside the `slides.map(...)` and will have its own state.

If you change the state of Slide it will render the component Slide, that's basically the idea of the hook [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

You can check the [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) docs also. When you want to change a value in the component without rendering you usually want to the useRef hook, not the useState