# React - child component re-renders even if it doesn't rely on the parent state

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

`console.log('Render test')` in my Test component runs twice.

The tests state is not used, I just put it there for an example. The Test component doesn't rely on the tests state but it still renders twice. Why?

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import AppTest from "./AppTest";

ReactDOM.render(<><AppTest /></>, document.getElementById("container"));
```

AppTest.js:

```
import Test from "./Test";
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function AppTest() {
    const [tests, setTests] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTests(['test1', 'test2']);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Test />
        </>
    );
}

export default AppTest;
```

Test.js:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

function Test() {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Render Test");
    });
    return (
        <h1>Test</h1>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: When a component re-renders, it also rerenders all of it's children (and it's children, and so on). This is just how react works. In 99% of cases, you don't need to worry about it, its very very fast. In that 1%, there are memoization functions available to prevent it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React.memo to prevent rerender unless props change - this has more info - [How to stop re render child component when any state changed in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219732/how-to-stop-re-render-child-component-when-any-state-changed-in-react-js)

Comment: Okay, this works. Is their a reason this is not default. This seems to make more sense then the default behavior. Is their any danger in adding this to every component?

Comment: @LaurentDhont the reason is 1) in most cases this "optimization" will actually be a net-loss in performance, and 2) your logic should not be affected by additional renders anyway (see React.StrictMode). Rendering is very fast. What you're asking about is considered a micro-optimization or pre-optimization. They aren't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The component Test is rendered twice because of the behaviour of the AppTest component. The useEffect function in AppTest modify the state of your component with  `setTests(['test1', 'test2']);` so the AppTest component is re-rendered.

As previously said, you can use memoization to avoid re-render Test component:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
const Test= React.memo(()=> {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Render Test");
    });
    return (
        <h1>Test</h1>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score -1):

The `useEffect` runs twice because it's missing a dependency array. Add an empty array to indicate it has no dependencies, and then you will not see multiple log statements:

```js
function Test() {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Render Test");
    }, []);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know but I wonder why. What does it mean?

Comment: This is exactly how it is explained in the API docs, "The default behavior for effects is to fire the effect after every completed render. That way an effect is always recreated if one of its dependencies changes." https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: It's by design. If you don't want it to run on every render, you add a dependency array and tell React which dependencies it should check before deciding whether to run the effect.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that components re-render even if they don't have state or props.

Comment: @LaurentDhont take it up with the React team. This is how it works.